# What does this "electric" mean and function here?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

In movie *Sin City* the actor says

> The wind rises, electric. She's soft and warm and almost weightless. Her perfume is a sweet promise that brings tears to my eyes.

I don't see what *electric* means here. Does it modify *the wind* ? Is this an appositive usage here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it qualifies the wind, you can read the sentence as: "The wind rises, it is electric."

It is  meaning number 3 of the *wiktionary* definition of [electric](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/electric) :

> Being emotionally thrilling; electrifying.

Saying that the *wind is electric* is a way of qualifying the emotions the wind at this particular moment produces on people: it electrifies them, makes them maybe agitated, maybe thrilled, excited...